# Detecting app activation from notification

Tags: xamarin.android, google-cloud-messaging

I have an application using GCM for push notifications. I already receive the message and act correctly when the app is opened. The problem is I need the app to open the specific article on the notification when it's closed.

How can I check if the app was opened from a notification and not the launcher and how to get said notification data?

Comment: I just realized my mistake. The notification was sent as notification and not as data. The system-generated notification just happened to look exactly like I wanted and thought it was being generated from the code. That's why the intent I received was empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> check if the app was opened from a notification and not the launcher

You could use [PendingIntent.GetActivity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int))  to implement this function. When you add this method in your `Notification`, it will retrieve a `PendingIntent` that will start a new `Activity`. Here is a basic sample :

```
//Set the activity, it will be opened when click the notification
var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(NotificationActivity));

intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);

intent.PutExtra("name", "York");
intent.PutExtra("Id", 1234);

var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);

var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
     .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
     .SetContentTitle("FCM Message")
     .SetContentText(messageBody)
     .SetAutoCancel(true)
     .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());
```

> how to get said notification data?

If use `Intent` to pass data as below :

```
intent.PutExtra("name", "York");
intent.PutExtra("Id", 1234);
```

When click the `notification` to open the `Activity`, you could restore data like this :

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (Intent != null)
    {
        string name = Intent.GetStringExtra("name");
        int id = Intent.GetIntExtra("Id", 0);
    }  
    ...
}
```

Comment: I came up with something like that, but the intent received was always empty. My mistake was sending the message as notification and not as data. I thought data was only used for FCM, I was wrong.